# Heating an 1ohm ressistor using mosfet as switch

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I need to heat an 1 ohm resistor  from 3.7v,1000mah battery  using an mosfet as switch  whose gate voltage is supplied through arduino digital pin output and supply to the arduino is also given from the same battery.
The problem i'm facing is that the ardunio nano is on but resistor does not get heated .
I have used:

1. irf640 mosfet
2. irl2203 mosfet

we tried changing mosfets but it did not work.
 [image]

Comment: Please spend 5 minutes properly formatting your question into something neater than a giant wall of text. Furthermore, add implementation details - how have you wired things up (diagrams help), what debugging steps have you tried,  etc.

Comment: What happens when you connect 1kohm resistor to 3.7V?

Comment: What is the voltage drop over R2? Are the grounds of your battery and arduino connected?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what the conducting IRF640 looks like graphically: -

[image]

If you had a gate-source voltage of 4.5 volts and put 3.7 volts across drain to source, the current that flowed might be 0.6 amps. If you wanted the volt drop across the MOSFET to be much less you could activate the gate at (say) 15 volts and then you could pull more than 10 amps.

So with a measly 3 volt gate drive your resistor is barely going to get warm at all.

For your application this MOSFET is unsuitable. You need to find a MOSFET with a much, much lower on resistance and one that is capable of going sub 50 milli ohm with a Vgs of 3 volts.

Even 50 milli ohm is a 5% error if you truly wanted 1 ohm placed across the 3.7 volt supply.

---

---

Following an edit by the OP, he also said that the IRL2203N didn't work. So, I suggest you measure the resistor to ensure it is 1 ohm. I also suggest that you measure the gate-source voltage to ensure that it is 3 volts. Basically double check everything but most importantly: -

```
Ensure that the MOSFET ground and Arduino grounds are connected
```

Comment: oh oh  but why does the circuit works when we when the give supply to the arduino nano thro laptop usb separetly

Comment: Because USB is, as far as I know at 5 volts.

Comment: R1 is not necessary, in fact it forms a resistor divider with R2, which divides the gate voltage unnecessarily. Ensure that you have 1) enough power on the Arduino side (so check that the Arduino output is at 5V when on), and 2) enough battery - the 1 ohm resistor means 3.7A of current, for that you do need a very big battery. An 1000mAh battery is simply not sufficient for this, check the max continuous current spec of the battery. (Expect less than 500mA continuous load.)

Comment: BigyanSubedi, You should add that info to your question.  And what do you mean by work?  3+A of current?  @GeeBee Sounds like an answer.

Comment: By work i mean to say that ressistor gets hot

Answer (score 1):

Use a better N-channel MOSFET, such as AOD508
RDS(ON) (at VGS = 4.5V) < 4.5mΩ
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/alpha-omega-semiconductor-inc/AOD508/785-1355-1-ND/3060910